# Is it possible to SQL inject into this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, code-injection

So basically, in my PHPMYADMIN I'm toying around with SQL injections so that I can eventually become a pen tester

```
SELECT *
FROM `ip` as ipstr
WHERE 'id' = $USERINPUT_HERE
ORDER BY
ipstr.id ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I'm having difficulty because it says that 'ipstr' is no longer defined when I try to inject it into my phpmyadmin.

I know that if it were a subquery, I would be able to do this. But its not a subquery, so how can I make something like the following work?

```
SELECT *
FROM `ip` as ipstr
WHERE 'id' = $USERINPUT_HERE
UNION ALL SELECT 1,2,3,4,5
ORDER BY
ipstr.id ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Somebody I know is saying it is possible to do this kind of injection, but I cannot figure out how to do it without rewriting the whole query and using subqueries. Thanks.

Comment: if there is an input coming directly from the user, `yes` - an sql injection is possible unless proper sanitization.

Comment: Could you give me an example about how the above is vulnerable to SQL injection? It would be appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see.  If the string contained `''; delete ip; select * from (select 1 as id) ipstr`, then the code might do something you don't expect.  (To be honest, the entire statement might get rejected because it is multiple statements, but this is an example.)

The solution to SQL injection is to use parameterized queries.  This is not a hard concept.  And it is a good habit.  You should get into that habit.